# I need to get vectors that contain elements from the lists in a certain order

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to get new vectors from the data I have. I have several lists, for example:

```
list1 = [a, b, c]
list2 = [d, e, f]
list3 = [m, n, o]
```

Output I want

```
vector1 = [a, d, m]
vector2 = [b, e, n]
vector3 = [c, f, o]
```

The first elements of the three lists are vector 1, the second elements are vector 2, and so on.

Comment: Please, be more specific. Are all the list? of the same size? Are there always just 3 lists?

Comment: Isn't this specific, these are the only three lists required for in the solutio

Comment: @PythonProgrammer: It matters because some solutions won't work properly (dropping data) if the sizes might not match, and simplifications for *very* specific cases might not work with slightly different input sizes/formats/etc. As written, `zip` is *the* solution, but it will lose data if the inputs have uneven sizes.

Comment: I see, I assumed here that OP only wants this solution for these three lists and  not any others though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to achieve this.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['m', 'n', 'o']
vector1, vector2, vector3 = map(list, zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

Comment: I would like to know how this works without enumerate()?

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems like it would just map the elements of list1 to vector1, however this isn't the case?

Comment: `zip` iterates through each of the lists element by element (note that it will stop once it hits the end of the shortest list), and returns tuples of the corresponding elements.  As the question asked for lists, I applied the `list` function to each tuple using `map`.

Comment: @PythonProgrammer: `zip` does pairwise iteration. So the first output from it is a `tuple` of the first item from each of its three arguments. The OP wants a `list`, so `map(list` converts the `tuple` to a `list`, and that first output is put in `vector1`. Then `zip` produces the `tuple` of all second items, which convert to `list`, which go in `vector2`, etc.

Comment: So `vector1, vector2, vector3 = zip(list1, list2, list3)` would create "vectors" as tuples instead of lists

Comment: Cool, I was originally trying something like ```vector1 =  [item for (item, idx,item, idx, item, idx) in (enumerate(list1), enumerate(list2), enumerate(list3)]``` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If all the list are of the same size, you could use numpy

```
M=np.array([list1, list2, list3])
vector1, vector2, vector3=M[:,0], M[:,1], M[:,2]
```

A more pure python way

```
L=[list1, list2, list3]
vector1=[L[i][0] for i in range(len(L))]
vector2=[L[i][1] for i in range(len(L))]
vector3=[L[i][2] for i in range(len(L))]
```

Or a more generic one

```
def getCol(i, *vec):
   return [vec[j][i] for j in range(len(vec)) if i<len(vec[j])]
vector1=getCol(0, list1, list2, list3)
```

(works with heteregeneous list size)